# PHP preg_match to retrieve text?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am not good with regular expressions, so I need a little bit of help.
I am trying to retrieve text like function inside a string like this:

```
$str_var = " i do not need this datavar(i need this),  i do not need this datavar(and also this),  and so on";        
preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $str_var, $match);
print_r($match)
```

I would like to have:

```
arr value 1 = datavar(i need this)
arr value 2 = datavar(and also this)
```

So far I am able to retrieve the text inside "this is it" and "this is it 2" but I need to retrieve the function name and the content with the pharentesis as well like: "datavar(i need this)" and "datavar(and also this)"

Any ideas

Comment: The "words" before the brackets, what characters can they be composed of? Only letters or also numbers as in your example?

Comment: only letters, function like: myfunc(here no problem, it can be anything).

Comment: nonono I had it working like [a-z](.*?) but it is a predefined text, it is:
datavar(here it can be whatever)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for if the words before the brackets are composed only of letters, as you confirmed in the comments to the question:

```
<?php
$subject = " i do not need this ineedthis(and also this),  i do not need this ineedthistoo(and also this 2),  and so on";
preg_match_all('#(\w+\([^)]+\))#', $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The output of above code is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ineedthis(and also this)
            [1] => ineedthistoo(and also this 2)
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ineedthis(and also this)
            [1] => ineedthistoo(and also this 2)
        )

)
```

---

UPDATE:

If that word before the brackets is the fixed, literal string `datavar`, then you can simplify above code to:

```
<?php
$subject = " i do not need this ineedthis(and also this),  i do not need this ineedthistoo(and also this 2),  and so on";
preg_match_all('#(datavar\([^)]+\))#', $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: I am sorry it is a predefined text "datavar" for the function name like: datavar(here whatever)

Comment: Sure, that simplifies the regular expression slightly, but not much of a change.

Comment: @arkascha I can already predict the next comment: `"But it should be datavar1, datavar2, etc."` :-)

Comment: Anyway, beat me to it :-)

Comment: it works pretty cool, it retrieves the full function with the text, in a couple of minutes will accept your answer, cheers !

Comment: Bro again just a last one, is it possible to bring content with perentheses like this:
datavar(and also this (i also bring this)  but this text is not retrieved, i need it too) 
as you can see it limits the content to the quickest ending parentheses ")" how can i get the last

Comment: That is a more tricky thing. The issue is that what you describe is not a regular language any more, seen from the point of view of complexity theory. That means a regular expression is not a mighty enough tool to really solve such tasks. You would need a "turing machine" instead of a "finite automate" for that. So code not based on a regular expression, but on a context sensitive model. You might succeed for certain cases with a regular expression, but not in a general way, which is why I would not recommend such an approach then.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the exact conditions, you could use something like:

```
(\w+\([^)]+\))
```

or in php:

```
preg_match('(\w+\([^)]+\))', $str_var, $match);
```

That means a serie of word characters `\w+` followed by a `(`, a number of characters that are not `)` and finally the closing `)`.

See an example [here](https://regex101.com/r/VZ3xis/1).

Comment: I am sorry it is a predefined text "datavar" for the function name like: datavar(here whatever)

Comment: @IvanJuarez Then adapt it to your needs.